# My requirement is to copy a content from excel, open terminal app, paste the copied content in terminal and execute

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vbscript, visual-basic

I am new to VB - So please guide me [Currently Terminal is opening up, but the focus still remains in excel.  I want to paste a copied value in terminal app.  guide me guys].  I am using Excel for mac 2011 [VB 14.1]

Code to paste is not written in the below code:

Code used:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

   Range("A1:A1").Select
   Selection.Copy

Externalapp = Shell("Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Terminal.app:" & _
              "Contents:MacOS:Terminal", vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate Externalapp

    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AppFocus function, but I've only used Excel VBA on Windows. What about trying the literal value of 1 instead of vbNormalFocus? `Shell("Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Terminal.app:Contents:MacOS:Terminal", 1)`

Comment: Not working :{  My current code is as below:

Comment: Sub Macro2()

Externalapp = Shell("Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Terminal.app:Contents:MacOS:Terminal", 1)
 
End Sub

Comment: What about using the `AppActivate` function instead?

Comment: I've also had issues with an external program losing focus when running a sub-procedure from the immediate window. If it is ran from the menu within Excel, you may have better results.

Comment: Do you mean like this??            Externalapp = Shell("Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Terminal.app:" & _
              "Contents:MacOS:Terminal", vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate Externalapp

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. If that doesn't work, you may have to try `AppleScript` or `MacScript`. I suggest editing your question to include what you have tried and including the version of Excel you are using (likely Excel 2011 or Excel 2016).

Comment: I have updated the content.  Kindly help.